# Why were wayfinder directions written on a dagger?

Tags: star-wars, plot-device, the-rise-of-skywalker

In The Rise of Skywalker, the heroes find the location of a Sith wayfinder by reading a runic inscription on Ochi's dagger.

What purpose does it serve to inscribe a random artifact's location on an unrelated tool? Was there some sort of relationship between the dagger and the wayfinders that I missed?

Comment: It wasn’t unrelated though was it? Also pointed to it when they got to the moon

Comment: Probably made for the purpose.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - But wasn't Ochi acting under direct orders from Palpatine? Meaning Palpatine was alive when Ochi used the dagger on <spoiler>a certain couple</spoiler>. Meaning it was given to him *before* Death Star II was blown up?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Maybe that'd be a second question - When did Ochi use the dagger?

Comment: Maybe it was all part of Palpatine's plan, leaving clues for Rey to eventually find him so that (spoilers)

Comment: @TheIronCheek: Wookiepedia gives Rey's birth as 15 ABY, so substantially after the events of ROTJ.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie: I think the dagger was probably used intentionally as it was to invest it with a history that would be psychometrically significant to Rey specifically, in order to further the plan, yes.

Comment: Ah, you’re right. Rey is much younger than the 30+ years between trilogies. If Palestine were still alive when Ochi used the dagger, Rey would’ve had to have been at least a decade older.

Comment: "Palestine", I'm dead! :D :D Stupid auto-correct.

Answer (score 16):

### The artifact wasn't random.

The shape of the blade's edge matched the shape of the second Death Star's wreckage from a certain point of view. The crossguard had a piece that pulled out to point to the part of the wreckage the wayfinder was in.

The dagger was either created with precognitive insight before the Battle of Endor (not impossible for a Force user), or created after the battle. In either case, *somebody* clearly wanted the Wayfinder to be located at a later point in time.

> Signs point to Palpatine, as the master manipulator of nine films. There's no *explicit* confirmation within the films themselves; no cackling admission of guilt/plan/foresight or "Yes, I did this and here's why."

Comment: What I'm wondering is how Rey knew exactly where to stand and which direction to look when she used the dagger.

Comment: Creating it after the Battle of Endor seems a bit more contrived since it would mean that 1. Whoever created the dagger knew that the Sith Wayfinder was in the wreckage and where. 2. That they didn't want to bother retrieving the Wayfinder themselves. 3. That they created the dagger for the purpose of allowing other people to find the Wayfinder.

Comment: +1 for "from a certain point of view"

Comment: @NathanK. The Force

Comment: @jamesdlin More contrived than the Force? :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I was hoping *somebody* would pick up on that. :)

Comment: This answer corrects my misconception but doesn't actually explain *why* which is the crux of my question.

Comment: @TheIronCheek: It seems like at least one of Palpatine's plans was served by Rey (or one of her close allies) arriving at the Sith planet.  To support this plan, Palpatine created at least one artifact (the dagger) and ensured it was placed somewhere Rey could reasonably find it and use it to make her way to the planet.  There's also no reason this was the *only* such artifact created, we just know this is the only one we found.

Comment: @T.J.L. "_That's_ not how The Force works"

Comment: @Jeff - Palpatine's plan wasn't for Rey to find her way to Exogol. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225240/why-would-the-emperor-groom-an-apprentice-if-he-had-other-plans