# How does the sith dagger-map work?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Having watched the new movie, it was a lot better than I expected from the last movie, but I really, really don't understand how the Sith dagger works.

It's a map

> to Exogol

but I don't understand how it ever even came to be, and how it works. It has Sith writing on it, with coordinates to

> the location of the Death Star, where the Sith Wayfinder is stored in the Personal Vault of Palpatine in his old Throne Room of the Death Star

But... this doesn't really seem to make any sense. The coordinates on the dagger are engraved, so there's no way that the coordinates can ever change. This means that the coordinates were engraved somewhere after the original trilogy.

The dagger also has some sort of extendable radius, that only makes sense if you stand in a very specific location and look through it

> at exactly one specific part of the crashed Death Star.

If a part of the structure collapses the map is no longer correct, so clearly the dagger depends entirely on the location being exactly as it is now.

> However, the other Wayfinder belonged to Darth Vader personally and was on his fortress on Mustafar. So apparently, these Wayfinders are a tool from the time of the first trilogy.

This to me seems to indicate that...

> the Death Star crashed, Palpatine survived and went on to Exogol to regenerate, but never bothered to retrieve the other Wayfinder from his old Treasure Vault, and in fact... went back and made the Sith Dagger to lead people to the spot, apparently hoping that the Death Star wouldn't be stripped for parts or collapse further, and then gave this dagger to his personal assassin Ochi and tasked him with finding and bringing back Rey.

This timeline, to me, seems entirely absurd, so I must be missing something. Who made this dagger, when did they make it and how does it work?

Comment: What baffles me is why Rey remembers Ochi's ship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why were wayfinder directions written on a dagger?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225111/why-were-wayfinder-directions-written-on-a-dagger)

Comment: The dagger bothers you, but not the fact that the Death Star somehow not only *didn't* blow up, but crashed on an _entirely different_ moon than the one it was in orbit around?